# (Visual Basic) Claims variables are undeclared when I (presumably) am declaring them

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have found many problems similar to mine, yet very few explanations in plain English of whats going on. I am attempting to declare a few class level variables to feed to multiple functions below them as argument, however I get a "null" error of sorts (from what I've found on the web). More specifically, I am declaring variables from textbox input that I'm converting to a double using CDbl() so I may use them in calculations for these functions.

The specific error message is "NullReferenceExpectation was unhandled by usercode".

The sources I've found hint that my problem is that these variables must be declared inside a method, or else visual studios flips out. I originally tried doing this, however in this instance it is a requirement I feed these functions the arguments they need from a class level variable, at least as far as I can tell....

I'm not so much looking for a correct version of my code, but more so to actually understand in full why this "exception" (what I believe to be jargon for an error) I keep seeing. I have the full code below for reference as well, even though I haven't finished cleaning up the output yet.

As you can tell I'm fairly new to visual basic, however I'm pretty decent with C++, PHP, and SQL; yet for some reason VB really throws me for a spin. Sorry I can't post my pic of the problem, apparently I don't have enough of points on this site to do so.

```
Public Class Form1

'declare textboxes as doubles
Dim expectedLoad As Double = CDbl(txtLoad.Text)
Dim length As Double = CDbl(txtLoad.Text)

Private Function test1(ByVal load As Double, length As Double, ByVal width As Double, ByVal area As Double)
    'Determine buckling load
    Dim bucklingLoad As Double = (0.3 * 1700000 * 3.14 * (width / 2)) / ((length / width) * (length / width))

    'return true is buckling load test is true
    If (bucklingLoad > load) Then
        test1 = True
    Else
        test1 = False
    End If

End Function


Private Function test2(ByVal load As Double, ByVal area As Double) As Boolean
    'Determine compressive stress
    Dim compressiveStress As Double = area * 445

    'return true if test is passed
    If (compressiveStress > expectedLoad) Then
        test2 = True
    Else
        test2 = False
    End If
End Function


Private Function test3(ByVal length As Double, ByVal width As Double) As Boolean
    'determine slenderness limits
    Dim slendernessLimits As Double = (length / width)

    If (slendernessLimits <= 50) Then
        test3 = True
    Else
        test3 = False
    End If
End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'list out column titles and alignments


    'do and list out test results for width 2
    'buckling load
    If (test1(expectedLoad, length, 2, (3.14 * ((2 / 2) * (2 / 2)))) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If

    'compressive stress
    If (test2(expectedLoad, (3.14 * ((2 / 2) * (2 / 2)))) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If

    'slenderness test
    If (test3(length, 2) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If


    'do and list out test results for width 4
    'buckling load
    If (test1(expectedLoad, length, 2, (3.14 * ((4 / 2) * (4 / 2)))) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If

    'compressive stress
    If (test2(expectedLoad, (3.14 * ((4 / 2) * (4 / 2)))) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If

    'slenderness test
    If (test3(length, 4) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If


    'do and list out test results for width 6
    'buckling load
    If (test1(expectedLoad, length, 2, (3.14 * ((6 / 2) * (6 / 2)))) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If

    'compressive stress
    If (test2(expectedLoad, (3.14 * ((6 / 2) * (6 / 2)))) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If

    'slenderness test
    If (test3(length, 6) = True) Then
        lstOut.Items.Add("True")
    Else
        lstOut.Items.Add("False")
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The problem, as Le-roy hinted below is that you are trying to assign values to your variables `expectedload` and `length` _before_ the textboxes have been instantiated.  Thus, they are null.  Even if they weren't null, they would not have any value in them at the point you call `CDbl` on them, so assigning them in that way is pointless anyway.  You should perform that assignment _after_ the user has had a chance to enter values into the textboxes.

Comment: Extremely helpful! I see exactly the issue, will have to make sure to watch for that in the future. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would declare those class-instance variables (`expectedLoad` and `length`) as `private` or `public` (instead of `Dim`). Also your `txtLoad` objects may not yet be initialised at the point of instantiating the `Form1` class.

Try something a little more robust such as:

```
Private ReadOnly Property ExpectedLoad As Double
    Get
        If txtLoad Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("txtLoad", "txtLoad was null")
        Dim result As Double = 0
        If Double.TryParse(txtLoad.Text, result) = True Then
            Return result
        Else
            Throw New Exception("txtLoad.Text could not be converted to type Double")
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Noted on the "Dim" aspect, yours and Chris Dunaway's responses really helped me out. I appreciate the patience, and now I know what to keep an eye out for in the future.